# ¿Cómo extraigo los caracteres en negrita de un docx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, docx, python-docx

Tengo [un docx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IljYiNZ6n2xHddMYCedSj4l97aBg7Med/view?usp=sharing) de artículos publicados en revistas de marketing que contiene escalas y me gustaria extraerlas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo con la siguiente escala me gustaria obtener el titulo: Ten-Item and Five-Item Presonality Inventories, las preguntas  *"I see my self as:"* y las respuestas.

```
{
   "title":"Ten-Item and Five-Item Presonality Inventories",
   "scales":{
      "I see myself as":{
         "answer0":"1. Extraverted, enthusiastic",
         "answer1":"2. Critical, quarrelsome",
         "answer2":"3. Dependable, self-disciplined",
         ...
      },
      "I see my self as":{
         "answer0":"Extraverted, enthusiastic (that is, sociable ... ",
         "answer1":"2. Agreeable, kind ...",
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

o algo similar si los nombres des escalas dupicadas son un problema.

Hasta hoy Puedo extraer el contenido por separado, con el siguiente código:

```
import pandas as pd

!pip install tika
from tika import parser 
!pip install python-docx 
from docx import *

# if you use colab, you need to have it in your drive in a "Books" folder
document = Document('/content/drive/My Drive/Books/handbook-of-marketing-scale-2011.docx')

dict_open = False
qas = {}
qa = {}
last_line_is_bold_or_italic = False
last_line_is_digit = False

for para in document.paragraphs:
    for run in para.runs:
        try:
            # we have a question and nothing before: begining of a q-aire 
            if run.bold or run.italic and last_line_is_digit == False: # first line must be bold # second must be numbers
                last_line_is_bold_or_italic = True
                question = run.text

            # we have an answer and last line was a question (last_line_is_bold_or_italic) or an answer (last_line_is_digit)
            # we are inserting an answer in a q-aire
            elif run.text[0].isdigit() and (last_line_is_bold_or_italic or last_line_is_digit):
                last_line_is_bold_or_italic = False
                last_line_is_digit = True
                number = run.text.split(".")[0]
                answer = run.text.split(".")[-1]
                qa[number] = answer

            # we have a question (last_line_is_bold_or_italic) and last line was an answer, we close the preceding question
            # we are inserting the q-aire in the dictionnary of all q-aires
            elif run.bold or run.italic and last_line_is_digit:
                last_line_is_digit = False
                # close dict
                qas[question] = qa
                qa = {}
                dict_open = False
              
            # we might have something bold, italics, ... but who knows what it is?
            # we reset
            else:
                last_line_is_bold_or_italic = False
                last_line_is_digit = False
                question = None
                pass

        except IndexError:
            last_line_is_bold_or_italic = False
            last_line_is_digit = False
            question = None
            if dict_open:
                   qa = {}
                   dict_open = False
            else:
                 pass
```

Pero obtengo:

```
{' ': {'11, 186–93': '',
  '2002': ' Professor Bearden served as the University SEC Faculty Athletics Representative from 2006 to 2010 and received the first Distinguished Service Award from the ',
  '23, 387–93': ''},
 ' slight agreement;': {'0, ': '0, ',
  '26 (June), 85–98': '',
  '34 (June), 456–67': ''},
 ' somewhat characteristic, ': {'1982 by the American Psychological Association': '',
  '3': '3',
  '42 (1), 116–31': ''},
 ' somewhat true, but with exceptions; ': {'4': '4'},
 ' uncertain, ': {'4': '4'},
 '.': {'05), respectively': '39 ',
  '28) was reportedfor the scale(Houseand Rizzo 1972,p': '',
  '7, 467–505': ''},
 'Academy of Marketing Science, ': {'1': ' In general, do you talk to your friends and neighbors about cable television:',
  '24 (2)': '24 (2)',
  '31, 55–64': '',
  '98\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '98\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES'},
 'Analytic/Holistic Thinking Scale: AHS': {'01)': '',
  '12, 341–52': '',
  '12, 663–82': '',
  '13, 121–37': '',
  '1995 by John Wiley & Sons, Inc': '',
  '1996 by Elsevier Science': '',
  '22, 41–53': '',
  '24–38': '',
  '288\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '288\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '51, 407–15': ''},
 'Assertiveness and Aggressiveness': {'432\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '432\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES'},
 'Attention to Social Comparison Information: ATSCI': {'128\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '128\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '224 sample': '',
  '30, 526–37': '',
  '4 ': '4 ',
  '50; and consumer behavior measures) show strong support for the validity of the ATSCI': '',
  '76, 461–71': ''},
 'Attitude Toward Private Label Products Scale': {'01) with measures of experiential shopping motives, compulsive buying, pleasure, and arousal, respec-tively': '',
  '3 (3), 239–49': '',
  '370\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '370\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '40 (August), 310–20': '',
  '5-point Likert-type scales': '',
  '7-point scales with endpoints indicated above': '',
  '79 (Summer), 77–95': '',
  '93 (college students)': ''},
 'Behavioral Identification Form: BIF': {'110 (3), 403–21': '',
  '290\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '290\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '57 (4), 660–71': ''},
 'Business Research, ': {'31': '31'},
 'Consumer Attitudes Toward Marketplace Globalization': {'27, 37–65': '',
  '29, 83–100': '',
  '392\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '392\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '6': '6'},
 'Consumer Involvement Profiles: CIP': {'18, 392–401': '',
  '1991 by University of Chicago Press': '',
  '230': '230',
  '234': '234',
  '240\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '240\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '30, 3–23': '',
  '31 (1), 3–23': '',
  '5 ': '5 ',
  '51 (July), 5–15': ''},
 'Consumer’s Need for Uniqueness: CNFU': {'44\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '44\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '58 subjects': '',
  '86 (October), 518–27': ''},
 'Customer-Based Reputation of a Service Firm: CBR Scale': {'23 (September), 227–39': '',
  '35, 127–43': '',
  '396\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '396\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '62, 924–30': ''},
 'Electronic Service Quality: E-S-QUAL': {'412\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '412\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '7 (February), 213–33': ''},
 'Emotions: Dimensions of Emotions: PAD': {'1997 by the University of Chicago': '',
  '24, 127–46': '',
  '310\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '310\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '91 (4), 780–95': ''},
 'Ethics: Improving Evaluations of Business Ethics': {'448\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '448\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES'},
 'Ethnocentrism: Consumer Ethnocentrism: CETSCALE': {'25 (1), 26–37': '',
  '28, 320–27': '',
  '92\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '92\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES'},
 'Gender Dimensions of Brand Personality': {'1997 by the American Marketing Association': '',
  '209 university students': '',
  '3': ' Overall quality of the original brand (1 ',
  '34 (August), 347–56': '',
  '34, 347–56': '',
  '342\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '342\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '346\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '346\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '4': ' Perceived difficulty in designing and making the extension (1 ',
  '46 (January), 105–19': ''},
 'General Self-Control': {'1, 2, 4, 8, and 11 compose the “hedonic” subscale': '',
  '78\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '78\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES'},
 'Horizontal and Vertical Individualism and Collectivism': {'51 (April), 407–15': '',
  '54\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '54\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '74 (1), 118–28': ''},
 'Innovativeness: Use Innovativeness': {'05) to “new product trial': '”',
  '116\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '116\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '118\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '118\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '1995 by Lawrence Erlbaum Associates, Inc': '',
  '4 (4), 329–45': ''},
 'Job Characteristic Inventory: JCI': {'20 (March), 31–44': '',
  '38 (May), 269–77': '',
  '4 ': '4 ',
  '456\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '456\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '480\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '480\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '84)': '',
  '9, 639–53': ''},
 'Journal of Consumer Research,': {'16': '16', '24)': ''},
 'Leadership: Transactional and Transformational Leadership': {'1996 by the American Marketing Association': '',
  '526\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '526\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '60, 89–105': ''},
 'Long-Term Orientation: LTO': {'01)': '',
  '10, 1–22': '',
  '16 (February), 64–73': '',
  '16 (February), 6–17': '',
  '18 (May), 133–45': '',
  '24 (4), 366–74': '',
  '26\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '26\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '28 (4), 674–89': '',
  '28 (June), 121–34': '',
  '31 (June), 209–19': '',
  '34, 100–17': '',
  '4': '4',
  '5-point scale labeled 1 ': '5-point scale labeled 1 ',
  '56 (2), 131–49': '',
  '7 (3), 309–19': '',
  '70 (1), 172–94': '',
  '78, 98–104': '',
  '88 (5), 879–903': '',
  '9 (June), 139–64': '',
  '9, 1–26': ''},
 'Meaning of Branded Products Scale': {'25, 82–93': '',
  '34, 347–56': '',
  '352\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '352\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES'},
 'Need to Evaluate: NES': {'05)': '',
  '1996 by the American Psychological Association': '',
  '38\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '38\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '5 ': '5 ',
  '70 (1), 172–94': ''},
 'Note: ': {'1 to 7': '1 to 7'},
 'Notes: ': {'1': '1',
  '15 (January), Pages 77–91': '',
  '29 (March), 551–65': ''},
 'Opinion Leadership': {'96\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '96\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES'},
 'Organizational Commitment': {'108, 17–94': '',
  '16, 321–38': '',
  '27, 333–44': '',
  '538\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '538\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '64, 295–314': ''},
 'Organizational Justice': {'540\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '540\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES'},
 'Personality and Social Psychology, ': {'01) between a measure of impulsivity and sensory innovativeness': '',
  '1990 by Elsevier Science': '',
  '20, 293–315': '',
  '42': '42'},
 'Positive and Negative Affect Scales (PANAS)': {'114 (all nonstudents)': '',
  '12, 281–300': '',
  '26 (February), 30–43': '',
  '316\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '316\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '54, 1063–70': ''},
 'Power: Dependence-Based Measure of Interfirm Power in Channels': {'01, one-tailed) indicated a reasonable degree of stability': '',
  '12, 177–87': '',
  '13': '',
  '2': '',
  '21': '',
  '34 (June), 324–40': '',
  '546\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '546\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '558\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '558\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '8': ''},
 'Pricing Tactic Persuasion Knowledge: PTPK': {'12 (December), 341–52': '',
  '382\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '382\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES'},
 'Purchasing Involvement: PI': {'1985 by the American Marketing Association': '',
  '268\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '268\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '49, 72–82': ''},
 'Reference Group Influence: Consumer Susceptibility to Reference Group Influence': {'140\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '140\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '7 (November), 1–15': ''},
 'Research, ': {'16': '', '31 (December), 551–56': '31 (December), 551–56'},
 'Response Profile: Viewer Response Profile: VRP': {'19, 37–46': '',
  '324\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '324\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '70), respectively': ''},
 'Salesperson Performance': {'1': '',
  '1993 by the American Marketing Association': '',
  '50 (1), 1–28': '',
  '512\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '512\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '520\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '520\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '57, 70–80': ''},
 'Satisfaction-Channel Satisfaction: SATIND and SATDIR': {'15), GFI ': '15), GFI ',
  '1984 by the American Marketing Association': '',
  '226–33': '',
  '32, 534–52': '',
  '35 (September), 382–97': '',
  '4 ': '4 ',
  '45 (1), 215–33': '',
  '54, 80–93': '',
  '586\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '586\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '76 (Spring), 11–32': ''},
 'Self-Concept Clarity: SCC': {'01)': '',
  '1996 by the American Psychological Association': '',
  '58\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '58\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '70 (1), 141–56': '',
  '82 Canadian students at the University of British Columbia': ''},
 'Service Convenience: SERVCON': {'35 (4), 144–56': '',
  '38 (May), 269–77': '',
  '418\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '418\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '64, 12–40': ''},
 'Service Quality of Retail Stores': {'1996 by Sage Publications': '',
  '24 (1), 3–16': '',
  '408\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '408\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '64, 12–40': ''},
 'Style of Processing Scale: SOP': {'1, 109–26': '',
  '12, 125–34': '',
  '1985 by University of Chicago Press': '',
  '296\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '296\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '36 (June), 56–72': '',
  '5 ': '5 '},
 'TV Program Connectedness Scale': {'148\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '148\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '30 (4), 526–37': ''},
 'Tension: Job-Induced Tension': {'1 ': '1 ',
  '510\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '510\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES'},
 'The Technology Readiness Index (or Techqual™)': {'122\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '122\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '2 (May),307–20': ''},
 'Value Consciousness and Coupon Proneness: VC and CP': {'30, 234–45': '',
  '386\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '386\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES'},
 'Vanity: Trait Aspects of Vanity': {'1995 by University of Chicago Press': '',
  '21, 612–26': '',
  '64\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '64\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES'},
 'Work-Family Conflict and Family-Work Conflict Scales': {'1996 by the American Psychological Association': '',
  '506\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES': '506\tHANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES',
  '81 (4), 400–10': '',
  '86, CFI ': '86, CFI '},
 'exceptions; ': {'1974 by the American Psychological Association': '',
  '3': '3',
  '30 (4), 526–37': '',
  '51, 125–39': ''},
 'medium relevance': {'3, ': '3, '}}
```

Comment: Pues, por el mismo contenido que tú mismo compartes, tiene toda la pinta de no mostrar marcadores de énfasis en el texto (o ningún otro).

Comment: @Alfabravo ¿Al menos el texto en negrita? ¿O el texto en cursiva? Eso enmarca las preguntas y respuestas cada vez

Comment: ¿Un PDF o un DOCX? Son problemas totalmente distintos.

Comment: @César me disculpe, pienso que es mucho más simple

Comment: Es muchísimo más simple porque el PDF puede no ser OCR y no hay forma. docx tiene toda la metadata de estilo y ya es buscar una librería...

Comment: Por otro lado, no sé exactamente a qué te refieres con "scales". Tal vez puedas aclarar esa parte.

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica Leyendo tu publicación, entiendo que lo que pones en el título ya lo has hecho, y en lugar de eso quieres ayuda sobre cómo construir el diccionario, ¿o me equivoco?

Comment: @DannyTalent si, eso es. He resuelto mi primer problema. Ese es el objetivo ahora.

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica ¿Hay algún patrón en el documento que hayas visto que ayude a identificar en qué secciones aparecen los datos que necesitas? Eso ayudaría bastante ya que no conocemos la estructura del .docx

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza gracias por tu comentario. Si hay un patrón ! El mismo que el sobre la foto. Hay esto en todo lo documento

Comment: Dándole una mirada rápida al PDF se identifican al menos 3 patrones, por ej. Pag 31, pag 34, pag 38, las tres tienen estructuras distintas. Resolver el patrón que muestras es relativamente sencillo, incluso solo desde el texto plano, pero te sirve resolver solo ese modelo de página?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho No me había dado cuenta, gracias por mostrármelo.  Sí, sirve resolver solo ese modelo de página

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que esto puede servir:

```python
import json

from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

def is_centered(paragraph):
  return paragraph.alignment == WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER

def is_header(text):
  return text.startswith("Chapter ") or text.startswith("HANDBOOK OF MARKETING SCALES")

def is_numbering(paragraph):
  return paragraph._p is not None and paragraph._p.pPr is not None and paragraph._p.pPr.numPr is not None

def is_subanswer(answers, text):
  return len(answers) > 0 and text[0].islower()

document = Document("handbook-of-marketing-scale-2011.docx")

chapter_2_found = False
appendix_found = False

title = None
scale = None
numbering_found = False
previous_text = None
answers = None
subanswers = None

result = []

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:

  text = paragraph.text
  if text == "":
    continue

  if not chapter_2_found and text == "Chapter 2\tTraits and Individual Difference Variables\t17":
    chapter_2_found = True
  
  if chapter_2_found and text == "Appendix to Inter-/Intrafirm Issues":
    break
  
  if not chapter_2_found or is_header(text):
    continue

  if is_centered(paragraph):
    title = text

  if is_numbering(paragraph):

    if not numbering_found:
      numbering_found = True
      scale = previous_text
      answers = []
      subanswers = []

    if is_subanswer(answers, text):
      subanswers.append(text)

    else:
      if subanswers:
        answers[-1] += ": " + ", ".join(subanswers)
        subanswers = []
      answers.append(text)

  elif numbering_found:

      numbering_found = False
      if answers and subanswers:
        answers[-1] += ": " + ", ".join(subanswers)
        subanswers = []

      if len(scale) > 1 and len(answers) > 2:
        result.append({"title": title, "scale": scale, "anwers": answers})

      scale = None
      answers = []
      subanswers = []

  previous_text = text

print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
```

Este script lee un archivo `handbook-of-marketing-scale-2011.docx` en el directorio actual y escribe el JSON resultado en la salida estándar. Si se almacena este código en `script.py` se puede ejecutar así: `python3 script.py`. Si se quiere guardar la salida en un archivo se puede ejecutar así: `python3 script.py > output.json`.

Este script itera por los párrafos del documento ignorando aquellos que están vacíos. Solo se consideran los párrafos entre el comienzo del capítulo 2 y el apéndice. La salida es un arreglo de objetos con una estructura como la del siguiente fragmento:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Ten-Item and Five-Item Personality Inventories",
    "scale": "I see myself as:",
    "anwers": [
      "Extraverted, enthusiastic",
      "Critical, quarrelsome",
      "Dependable, self-disciplined",
      "Anxious, easily upset",
      "Open to new experiences, complex",
      "Reserved, quiet",
      "Sympathetic, warm",
      "Disorganized, careless",
      "Calm, emotionally stable",
      "Conventional, uncreative"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Ten-Item and Five-Item Personality Inventories",
    "scale": "I see myself as:",
    "anwers": [
      "Extraverted, enthusiastic (that is, sociable, assertive, talkative, active, NOT reserved or shy)",
      "Agreeable, kind (that is, trusting, generous, sympathetic, cooperative, NOT aggressive or cold)",
      "Dependable, organized (that is, hard-working, responsible, self-disciplined, thorough, NOT care-less or impulsive)",
      "Emotionally stable, calm (that is, relaxed, self-confident, NOT anxious, moody, easily upset, or easily stressed)",
      "Open to experience, imaginative (that is, curious, reflective, creative, deep, open-minded, NOT conventional)"
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

La propiedad `title` resulta del último texto centrado encontrado. La propiedad `scale` resulta del último texto encontrado antes de una numeración. La propiedad `answers` resulta de los párrafos que conforman una numeración.

Algunas respuestas tienen opciones. En el script se almacenan en `subanswers` y se unen al texto de la respuesta separadas por comas y precedidas por dos puntos. Ejemplo: `Make gifts instead of buying: never, occasionally, frequently, usually, always`.

La clave para resolver este problema fue encontrar la forma de distinguir numeraciones de otros párrafos. Usando `python-docx` encontré que se puede hacer usando `paragraph._p.pPr.numPr`. Esta aproximación tiene la desventaja de usar una variable de uso interno `_p` de los párrafos, pero parece ser la única opción disponible en este momento dadas las limitaciones de la biblioteca.

Luego de terminar de procesar una escala se usa la siguiente condición para determinar si es válida: `len(scale) > 1 and len(answers) > 2`. A veces, por la estructura misma del documento, se interpretan como escalas algunas numeraciones para las cuales el nombre de la escala es demasiado corto o tiene muy pocas respuestas. Con esta condición se excluyen esas posibles escalas y no se incluyen en los resultados.

[Aquí](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/healarconr/f4415536920117cff98edc566ce59a68/raw/06c9d3968588f1c9096fbdd9c9c94d1c2a232105/output.json) se puede observar el JSON resultado.

Comment: ¡Yo también lo creo! Bien hecho, acepto la respuesta, dejo la bonificación abierta un poco más si alguien tiene una buena idea y entonces será tuya!